# JSON.Net deserialize object containing xml

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON object with a specific field whose value is always XML, as follows:

```
{
    ...
    "XmlValue": "<tag1><etc></etc></tag1>"
    ...
}
```

I'm using JSON.Net as the deserializer.  I want to make this deserialize to a class like this:

```
public class ObjectContainingXml
{
    ...
    public XElement XmlValue { get;set; }
    ...
}
```

When I try, using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectContainingXml>(input)`, I get this exception: `XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object.`

Is there a way to make this natively work in JSON.Net without treating that field as a string and then parsing the field to XML manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no built-in way to perform that kind of deserialization with JSON.Net.

Background:

`XmlNodeConverter` is meant to serialize XML as JSON. For example, a node like

```
<root><p>Text1<span>Span1</span> <span>Span2</span> Text2</p></root>
```

will be serialized as

```
{"root":{"p":{"#text":["Text1"," Text2"],"span":["Span1","Span2"]}}}
```

If you need XML to be serialized to string and back, you'll need to implement a custom `JsonConverter`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's not quite what I'm asking about.  I have JSON already.  The JSON contains XML, as shown in the question.  I am calling the native JsonConvert.DeserializeObject function on that JSON object, and the exception I noted is what comes back.  JsonConvert.SerializeObject works on this class.

Comment: @dodexahedron What is not clear? There is no built-in way to do what you want. If you need this, you'll have to implement your `JsonConverter` class (two methods, one line of code each). Then either pass converter to `DeserializeObject` method or decorate properties in your object with your converter.